# Does Firebase Hosting support routing using Express.js. I want to host a dynamic Node.js application in firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Can firebase hosting be used to deploy a node.js application that requires dynamic routing. Why do they call that hosting can be used to deploy single page app.

[Firebase Hosting project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCZQt.png)

Something like this:

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var homeRouter = require('./routes/home');
```

And then have the routes in the routing folder

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail.

Comment: @DougStevenson Revised the above question. Thanks !

Comment: I still don't understand.  You've tagged this question with both Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions.  What are you trying to do with the both of them together?  Are you trying to set up routes on the client or server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Functions do support Express.js routing.

You can read more in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) or follow [this medium post](https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-86ed26f9144c) for more of a walkthrough.

**Edit:**

For more on using the express router with module imports take a look at [this blog](https://www.terlici.com/2014/09/29/express-router.html).

Comment: Hi Eric, I understand that it does support express.js routing. But can we instantiate multiple routes as given above in outr index.js file and export each route ?

Comment: Without the content of the 'routes/*' files I can't really tell. However, if you're trying to register routes via modules, you should look into this: https://www.terlici.com/2014/09/29/express-router.html 

It shows you a way to register routes via the app.use(require('...')) syntax by using the express router.

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
 "hosting": {
   // ...

   // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
   "rewrites": [ {
     "source": "**", // <<< Do this in your firebase.json
     "function": "app"
   } ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.